# Autoit - how to find dupes in two strings

Tags: autoit

anyone help please

I have a function that outputs a list of names to an array. I've parsed the list into a string that shows exactly what I want.
I have a second list of names that I want to compare to the first list and print out the details if they are different.

Example: If string = CCleaner 5.5 then prog1 is out of date. I want it to show this

```
#Include <Date.au3>
#Include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Local $prog1 = "CCleaner 5.29"
Local $prog2 = "Defraggler 2.21"
Local $string
Local $aList = _UninstallList("", "","Publisher|InstallLocation|DisplayVersion")

for $1 = 0 to ubound($aList) - 1
    $string &= $aList[$1][2] & " " & $aList[$1][6] & @CRLF
Next
msgbox(0, "", $string)
```

Comment: If you want to search a string in another string then just use StringInStr.

Comment: I can only see one list and two variables in your example code. If you really got two lists, then you could use 2 nested loops and compare every element of the outer loop to the array iterated with the inner loop. Or you might want to use [ArraySearch](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_ArraySearch.htm). Or [ArrayToString](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_ArrayToString.htm) together with [StringInString](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringInStr.htm)....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autoit: compare 2 array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43774434/autoit-compare-2-array)

Answer (score 0):

Several years ago, I wrote a function to compare lists or arrays. I think this can help you.

```
;==================================================================================================
; Function Name:   _GetIntersection($Set1, $Set2 [, $GetAll=0 [, $Delim=Default]])
; Description::    Detect from 2 sets
;                  - Intersection (elements are contains in both sets)
;                  - Difference 1 (elements are contains only in $Set1)
;                  - Difference 2 (elements are contains only in $Set2)
; Parameter(s):    $Set1    set 1 (1D-array or delimited string)
;                  $Set2    set 2 (1D-array or delimited string)
;      optional:   $GetAll  0 - only one occurence of every different element are shown (Default)
;                           1 - all elements of differences are shown
;      optional:   $Delim   Delimiter for strings (Default use the separator character set by Opt("GUIDataSeparatorChar") )
; Return Value(s): Succes   2D-array    [i][0]=Intersection
;                                       [i][1]=Difference 1
;                                       [i][2]=Difference 2
;                  Failure  -1  @error  set, that was given as array, is'nt 1D-array
; Note:            Comparison is case-sensitiv! - i.e. Number 9 is different to string '9'!
; Author(s):       BugFix (AutoIt@bug-fix.info)
;==================================================================================================
Func _GetIntersection(ByRef $Set1, ByRef $Set2, $GetAll=0, $Delim=Default)
    Local $o1 = ObjCreate("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Local $o2 = ObjCreate("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Local $oUnion = ObjCreate("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Local $oDiff1 = ObjCreate("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Local $oDiff2 = ObjCreate("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Local $tmp, $i
    If $GetAll <> 1 Then $GetAll = 0
    If $Delim = Default Then $Delim = Opt("GUIDataSeparatorChar")
    If Not IsArray($Set1) Then
        If Not StringInStr($Set1, $Delim) Then
            $o1.Add($Set1)
        Else
            $tmp = StringSplit($Set1, $Delim)
            For $i = 1 To UBound($tmp) -1
                $o1.Add($tmp[$i])
            Next
        EndIf
    Else
        If UBound($Set1, 0) > 1 Then Return SetError(1,0,-1)
        For $i = 0 To UBound($Set1) -1
            $o1.Add($Set1[$i])
        Next
    EndIf
    If Not IsArray($Set2) Then
        If Not StringInStr($Set2, $Delim) Then
            $o2.Add($Set2)
        Else
            $tmp = StringSplit($Set2, $Delim)
            For $i = 1 To UBound($tmp) -1
                $o2.Add($tmp[$i])
            Next
        EndIf
    Else
        If UBound($Set2, 0) > 1 Then Return SetError(1,0,-1)
        For $i = 0 To UBound($Set2) -1
            $o2.Add($Set2[$i])
        Next
    EndIf
    For $tmp In $o1
        If $o2.Contains($tmp) And Not $oUnion.Contains($tmp) Then $oUnion.Add($tmp)
    Next
    For $tmp In $o2
        If $o1.Contains($tmp) And Not $oUnion.Contains($tmp) Then $oUnion.Add($tmp)
    Next
    For $tmp In $o1
        If $GetAll Then
            If Not $oUnion.Contains($tmp) Then $oDiff1.Add($tmp)
        Else
            If Not $oUnion.Contains($tmp) And Not $oDiff1.Contains($tmp) Then $oDiff1.Add($tmp)
        EndIf
    Next
    For $tmp In $o2
        If $GetAll Then
            If Not $oUnion.Contains($tmp) Then $oDiff2.Add($tmp)
        Else
            If Not $oUnion.Contains($tmp) And Not $oDiff2.Contains($tmp) Then $oDiff2.Add($tmp)
        EndIf
    Next
    Local $UBound[3] = [$oDiff1.Count,$oDiff2.Count,$oUnion.Count], $max = 1
    For $i = 0 To UBound($UBound) -1
        If $UBound[$i] > $max Then $max = $UBound[$i]
    Next
    Local $aOut[$max][3]
    If $oUnion.Count > 0 Then
        $i = 0
        For $tmp In $oUnion
            $aOut[$i][0] = $tmp
            $i += 1
        Next
    EndIf
    If $oDiff1.Count > 0 Then
        $i = 0
        For $tmp In $oDiff1
            $aOut[$i][1] = $tmp
            $i += 1
        Next
    EndIf
    If $oDiff2.Count > 0 Then
        $i = 0
        For $tmp In $oDiff2
            $aOut[$i][2] = $tmp
            $i += 1
        Next
    EndIf
    Return $aOut
EndFunc  ;==>_GetIntersection
```