# Compare two arrays of .ini file entries

Tags: arrays, autoit

I have one .ini file as below:

```
[Step]
A=DONE
B=DONE
C=DONE
D=DONE
```

I need to get the `[Step]` section and put it in an array . Below is what I do:

```
$iniSection_Step = "Step"
$PrevStep = ""
Local $Prev = IniReadSection($iniPath_LogFile, $iniSection_Step)

For $i = 1 To $Prev[0][0]
    $PrevStep = $PrevStep &"|"& $Prev[$i][0]
Next
Global $PrevArray = StringSplit($PrevStep,"|",1)
```

The `_ArrayDisplay()` result:

```
Row|Col 0
 [0]|5
 [1]|
 [2]|A
 [3]|B
 [4]|C
 [5]|D
```

Now I need to compare the array with another and if an element exists in both, it will increment one array.

```
For $j = 0 To UBound($array_StepComplete) - 1
    if StringInStr($array_StepComplete[$j],$PrevArray[$i]) Then
        GUICtrlSetData($Input_PresentStep,$array_StepComplete[$j+1])
    EndIf
Next
```

This will increment one array but if someone deletes the content of .ini file as below:

```
  [Step]
  A=DONE

  C=DONE
  D=DONE
```

The code will increment one array but it does not check if the element exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood: `Compare two arrays and do some action if two elements match.`

First you need to clear things up. **What do you want to compare?** The **order** obvious **does matter** .. so I decided to **Loop on the dynamical array** first and if I found a matching pair I also exiting the loop for resource reasons ...

```
Local $aSteps = IniReadSection("Steps.ini", "Step")
If @error Then
    ConsoleWrite("#1 An error occured while reading the 'Steps.ini' file." & @CRLF)
    Exit
EndIf

Local $aAllsteps = IniReadSection("Steps.ini", "Allsteps")
If @error Then
    ConsoleWrite("#2 An error occured while reading the 'Steps.ini' file." & @CRLF)
    Exit
EndIf

; loop on the dynamical array first
For $i = 1 To $aSteps[0][0]
    ; then loop on the static array for each element
    For $y = 1 To $aAllsteps[0][0]
        ; check if the elements match
        If $aSteps[$i][0] = $aAllsteps[$y][0] Then
            ; if the element match print out and exit loop for resource reason
            ConsoleWrite("MATCH - " & $aSteps[$i][0] & @CRLF)
            ExitLoop
        EndIf
    Next
Next
```

**Steps.ini**

```
[Step]
A=DONE
C=DONE
D=DONE
[Allsteps]
A=DONE
B=DONE
C=DONE
D=DONE
```

**Output**

```
MATCH - A
MATCH - C
MATCH - D
```